# Java Hadoop MapReduce Multiple Keys Values

Tags: java, hadoop

I am implementing a movie recommendation system in `Java` and have been following this website [Link Here](http://aimotion.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/introduction-to-recommendations-with.html)

Input:
`userId movieRatingCount,ratingSum,(movieId,movieRating)`

```
17    1,3,(70,3)
35    1,1,(21,1)
49    3,7,(19,2 21,1 70,4)
87    2,3,(19,1 21,2)
98    1,2,(19,2)
```

the code:

```
def pairwise_items(self, user_id, values):
    item_count, item_sum, ratings = values
    #print item_count, item_sum, [r for r in combinations(ratings, 2)]
    #bottleneck at combinations
    for item1, item2 in combinations(ratings, 2):
        yield (item1[0], item2[0]), \
                (item1[1], item2[1])
```

Output: `firstMovieId, secondMovieId firstRating,secondRating`

```
19,21  2,1
19,70  2,4
21,70  1,4
19,21  1,2
```

For example, for userId 49, he watched 3 movies. The output will be

```
firstMovie, secondMovie firstMovieRatings, secondMovieRatings
firstMovie, thirdMovie firstMovieRatings, thirdMovieRatings
secondMovie, thirdMovie secondMovieRatings, thirdMovieRatings
```

For user who watched 1 movie, that output will be skipped.

Is it possible to translate this python code to Java? I have no clue what the `map output key and value` will be. As well as the way to  tackle this problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What if the user has watched only one movie? What will be the output then? Also, if user has watched 3 movies, do you also need: 19,21,70 2,1,4? I assume you need combinations of 2?

Comment: Update the question for all these scenarios, mentioned in previous comment

Comment: @ManjunathBallur What I think is, that user along with movie ratings will be skipped/ ignored.

Comment: I have edited the question please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mapper Logic:**

1. Assumes that input has key/values as tab separated. For e.g. "49    3,7,(19,2 21,1 70,4)"
2. In the value, it searches for "(" and parses out the string between "(" and ")"
3. It emits (key,value) as (UserId, (movieId,movieRating)). For e.g. for the record "49      3,7,(19,2 21,1 70,4)", it emits key:49, value: 19,2 21,1 70,4

**Reducer Logic:**

1. It splits the value on blank (" "). For e.g. it splits "19,2 21,1 70,4" into 3 strings: "19,2", "21,1" and "70,4". These values are added to an ArrayList
2. All the 2-way combinations for these values are computed.
3. Finally these combinations are emitted to output.

Following is the code:

```
package com.myorg.hadooptests;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MovieGroupings {

    public static class MovieGroupingsMapper
            extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text , Text, Text>{

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String valueStr = value.toString().trim();
            String[] tokens = valueStr.split("\t"); // Assume key/values to be tab seperated. For e.g. "17    1,3,(70,3)"

            if(tokens.length == 2) {
                int index = tokens[1].indexOf('('); // Search for "(" character
                if(index != -1)
                {
                    context.write(new Text(tokens[0]), new Text(tokens[1].substring(index+1, tokens[1].length() - 1)));  // Exclude '(' and ')'
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class MovieGroupingsReducer
            extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
                           Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            for (Text value : values) {
                String[] tokens = value.toString().split(" "); // Split the values based on blank character

                if(tokens.length >= 2) // Ignore if there is only one movie
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
                        for(int j = i + 1; j < tokens.length; j++) {
                            String groupings = tokens[i] + "," + tokens[j]; // Add 2 movies with ",". For e.g. "19,2,21,1"
                            String[] moviesAndRatings = groupings.split(",");
                            if (moviesAndRatings.length == 4)
                                context.write(new Text(moviesAndRatings[0] + "," + moviesAndRatings[2]),
                                        new Text(moviesAndRatings[1] + "," + moviesAndRatings[3]));
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "MovieGroupings");
        job.setJarByClass(MovieGroupings.class);
        job.setMapperClass(MovieGroupingsMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MovieGroupingsReducer.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(5);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/in/in5.txt"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/out/"));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1);
    }
}
```

For the following input:

```
17      1,3,(70,3)
35      1,1,(21,1)
49      3,7,(19,2 21,1 70,4)
87      2,3,(19,1 21,2)
98      1,2,(19,2)
```

Output generated is:

```
19,21   2,1
19,70   2,4
21,70   1,4
19,21   1,2
```

Comment: There is one problem thou. When I was trying to map the output key and value only, (without going through the reducer) the output becomes `98    19,2` `17    70,3` `35    21,1`

Comment: Then, I have no idea why the output file is 0bytes. Given that I haven't changed any code above. `File Output Format Counters Bytes Written=0`

Comment: I was using the entire code as shown above and havent changed anything. The input file is exactly the same as above as well.

Comment: For that, I have changed it to 1 blankspace with `split(" ")` I tried `split("\\s+")` too. It still doesnt work.

Comment: Obviously it won't work. You need to change the logic, if you split by (" "). Because (" ") is contained in the values also. For e.g. "(19,2 21,1 70,4)" this contains 3 (" ") blanks. How it will work? I coded with the assumption that key/value are separated by tabs and my code works perfectly for that. If you introduce (" ") between key/value, then you need to change the logic accordingly. My answer is correct. Also, in the mapper, after splitting, I am checking "if(tokens.length == 2)". If number of tokens is not 2, it will ignore that record. You need to handle this if you split by (" ").

Comment: ahh right! small changes makes a huge difference. I am so sorry for that small error keeping you busy.

Comment: I can confirm the code is working with the test file above. However, if 1 user rated like 30 movies, and with many users, making a big file (around 70mb), the reducer task stuck at 67% `INFO mapreduce.Job: map 100% reduce 67%` Do you know any reasons behind this?

Comment: I have updated the code. I removed "combinations()" function. Also, I have added 5 reducers (job.setNumReduceTasks(5);). Using 5 reducers, I crunched the data given by you and job took 15 minutes. You can use more reducers if you want. Check, if this program works.